# Wordpress Evenly Spaced Menu Wrong in Firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, menu

Thanks to these forums I was able to find the proper code to get my wordpress menu to display evenly across the screen. The problem I'm having is with firefox on a display that is 1400x900. In google or IE it adjusts to the different screen resolution fine. In firefox the last two menu items end up on second row. The website address is: http://www.homeinsurance.svtwebdesign.com

Firefox looks like this:
http://www.homeinsurance.svtwebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Firefox.png

My code is as follows:

```
ul#menu-mainmenu {
display:table;
width: 100%;
margin:0 0;}
ul#menu-mainmenu li {
 width: auto;              
 margin: 0 30px 0 20px;}
```

This was the only code I could get to work. Any assistance would be hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo in your question? I'm finding the menu overflows into a second line at 1199px screen width. I'm finding this happens at the same width for both Chrome and Firefox. You may want to check what browser version you are using. Then at 800px the menu converts to the mobile menu. This also happens on Chrome and Firefox for me.  I am also using http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ to test this.

You should use media queries to change the widths, paddings and/or margins of elements in your menu as the width of your viewing screen changes. Here's an example:

```
ul#menu-mainmenu li{
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    ul#menu-mainmenu li{
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
}
```

The css within the media query only takes effect if the screen is 1200px wide or more. If the screen is less than 1200px wide only the standalone css takes effect. By setting the margins lower in the standalone css, you get a smaller width menu for the same amount of links.

Read more about media queries at:

- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp